# Shell script to read the output of another script

Tags: shell, unix

I need to write a shell script which reads the output from another shell script (results.sh)and writes the result to a flat file.

Basically We dont have control and permission to change the results.sh but are allowed to access the results.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about something which output redirection (`results.sh > outfile`) would not handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
results.sh > log.txt
mapfile b < log.txt
```

output will be saved to `log.txt` and array variable `b`

Answer (score 0):

script `a.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $1
```

script `b.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read line
do echo "read: $line"
done
```

test:

```
chmod +x *.sh
a.sh "something" | b.sh
```

output:

> read: something

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using pipe:

```
./results.sh | ./yourNewScript.sh > flat.txt
```

or

```
bash results.sh | bash yourNewScript.sh > flat.txt
```

depends on how you run the script (./script needs the file to have executable bit -- chmod +x script).

Using | results sends directly it's output to yourNewScript. > writes output of yourNewScript to file flat.txt